# Invoking program with ExecutorService in newSingleThreadExecutor fashion

Tags: java, glassfish-3

Inside my JSF2.0 web, I am invoking some shell scripts in background one thread at a time. I need to wait until all the these programs are invoked successfully. Below is the snippet of the code-

```
    ExecutorService taskExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    for (String script : scriptList){
        taskExecutor.execute(new Runnable() {
             @Override
             public void run() {
                try {
                    log.info("Trying to start script " +script);
                    startScript(program);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    log.error("Exception ." + ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
    }
    taskExecutor.shutdown();

    try {
        taskExecutor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        log.error("InterruptedException ." + e.getMessage());
    }
    // Now I can proceed further can call other methods
```

The shell scripts, I am running from the above code shows `stdout` at runtime. I want to invoke scripts in background one by one without capturing their `stdout`. I don't want to wait until their completion. Only invoke signal.

Comment: So you are executing scripts and capturing their `stdout` without actually wanting that? If so, that does not seem as an `ExecutorService` issue. More of a thing in your `startScript()` method.

Comment: I want to invoke scripts in background one by one without capturing their `stdout`. I don't want to wait until their completion. Only invoke signal.

Comment: Can you provide a some of the `startScript()` code? If you only want to invoke the scripts, why do you have the `awaitTermination()` part?

Comment: `startScript()` simply calling script using `sh myScipt.sh`. Actually It seems like after invoking script, the code hangs (may be it is waiting for the `stdout`) and my only concern is to invoke the script (don't need `stdout`). Just a start signal in short

Comment: Removing the `awaitTermination()` part won't do what you want? You know what that `awaitTermination()` part is doing, right?

Comment: @acdcjunior: I observed that something is going mysterious... threads are waiting somewhere, the methods which are after the `ExecutorService`, are calling :(

Comment: I'm not sure I get this last comment of yours... Can you rephrase?

Comment: @acdcjunior: After the code, i want to call some methods. In the logs, i can see that these methods are getting called before all the scripts are invoked

Comment: `awaitTermination()` waits till the end of the scripts, is that so? How much time is that? Maybe you should change the scripts and make them generate some kind of signal (like a file) that they started, and just continue to execute your methods if all signals exist.